# Implementing Biconomy on Safe Contract

Tags: solidity, gnosis, safe

Does anyone know how i can implement biconomy on Safe Contracts?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution . When integrating with frontend or backend you need to make sure that the message should be made of the safe transaction and should be signed by the user .